# Preview mode on Google Tag Manager does not work for me (timeout)

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have installed Google Tag Manager on my sites but since the new version of Google Tag Manager, I cannot use the preview option. Each time I click on it, I see my website page opening but get then the following error: "Tag Assistant could not connect to a tag on..A timeout occurred while attempting to connect."

How can I resolve this issue?
Thanks
Best

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that I had my ad blocker on. When I turned it off, it worked.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. On this new version, before use the preview mode, you need to submit at least an empty container, then perform your preview mode like always.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Opening GTM in incognito and then running the preview mode fixed it for me. I'm guessing its one of my extensions.

Comment: is this meant as a comment

Comment: @StupidWolf no, I had the same issue as OP and this is how I resolved it.